# gunicorn eventlet worker keeps restarting

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn, google-cloud-pubsub, eventlet

I have a `Flask` app and I use the `gunicorn` as a web server with `eventlet` (`python -m gunicorn -k eventlet <app_here>`). One of the submodules is using the `Google Cloud Pub/Sub` service and is the one that's causing the worker to restart. In particular, it's the 3rd line here:

```
subscription_name = 'projects/{project_id}/subscriptions/{sub}'.format(project_id=pro_id, sub=sub_id)
subscriber_ = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient(credentials=credentials_)
streaming_pull_future = subscriber_.subscribe(subscription=subscription_path, callback=test_callback) # ISSUE LINE
```

**The error I get is**:

```
[CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT
Listening for messages on projects/....
[ERROR] Socket error processing request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 65, in handle
util.reraise(*sys.exc_info())
File "../python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 626, in reraise
raise value
File "../python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base_async.py", line 38, in handle
listener_name = listener.getsockname()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

**What I tried so far**

- If I remove `gunicorn` and `eventlet` (i.e. `python <app_here>`) that module works as expected but of course not the rest (backend/frontend).
- I've tested with different `gunicorn` and `eventlet` versions, with no luck.
- If I synchronously pull for new messages (and remove the `subscriber_.subscribe()`), it works but it's not the recommended way.

The implementation of the `pubsub` is based on [gcp pubsub docs](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#retrieve_custom_attributes_using_the_high-level_client_library) with simply adding some credentials.

```
python3.8
eventlet 0.30.2
gunicorn 20.1.0
google-api-core 2.11.1
google-cloud-pubsub 2.18
Flask 2.2.3
```

Is there a setting in the `pubsub` or the `eventlet` that I'm missing and would make it work?